# How to create package folders with javac command

Tags: java, cmd, package

I am compiling java file with command prompt with some package name come.test.
But while running with `java` command it gives no class definition  error. If I compile with IDE it is running because folders are created like `com\test`

How can I get those folders if I compile with `javac` command.

Comment: Be sure that you use the right path when calling javac. For example : C:\...\com\test\javac className.java

Comment: my code is                                                   package com.ics.test;

public class TestPackage{
 
 public static void main(String args[]){
  System.out.println("Hello World");
 }
}                                                                    And I have saved this file with TestPackage.java in "C:\Users\dharisis\Desktop\Dharisi" folder                        I used javac and TestPackage.class is generated.                 But when I am trying to run with java command, I am getting no class deff exception

Comment: With cmd prompt, you can compile like this C:\Users\dharisis\Desktop\Dharisi\src\com\ics\test\javac TestPackage.java. Note that Eclipse has created "src" folder for your source files, so don't forget it. Then after you can run C:\Users\dharisis\Desktop\Dharisi\src\com\ics\test\java TestPackage.

Answer (score 2):

For such questions, when an online search at oracle does yield immediate results, try

```
javac -help

javac -source 1.8
      -target 1.8
      -encoding UTF-8
javac -d target/classes         --> generated classes
      -s src/main/java          --> generated source files
      src/main/java/x/y/*.java  --> java files to be compiled
```

The directory `target/classes` should exist. Package folders are created under `classes` (`x/y`).